# Retrieving Patient's History

Tags: commcare

I am using Commcare to develop Electronic Medical Records system but can't figure out how in the Consulting room the clinician would have access to the patient's history since the data would have been sent you the server.

Would be grateful for any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to configure your app to create a "case" for each patient. Historical information about the patient can then be stored on that case, or other "child" cases representing past visits could be associated with the patient case. The following two pages in the commcare documentation will be helpful to you:

- [Case management fundamentals](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Fundamentals+-+Case+Management)
- [Basic case management tutorial](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Basic+Case+Management+Tutorial)